Unity Ads Mediation and IronSource
Im installing Unity Ads Mediation to show ads in my game. I see the primary network is IronSource but you can install more networks.
Also I see that on IronSource dashboard you can install more networks to get mediation. So if I do this, I also need to install the network on the Unity plugin? Or setting up on IronSource is enough?
